# Hover transition effect not working as intended

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have created the following navigation bar:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6eQd/)

If I'm not mistaken, it should work in JSFiddle. Both the background and border will fade in when hovering the links - at least that's what it does on my computer. So far so good.

Now, the problem is, when I put this navigation bar on my current project, it bugs like crazy. In IE and Chrome. Mostly in IE though (IE11). In IE, the effect only works sometimes, and usually only the border will appear, while the background will not. And if it works, then it's not all the links, but maybe only one.
In chrome, the background do appear, but it is not the same color as I want it to be - only in one of the links :/

It's very confusing, and on my computer, it works great when I put it into JSFiddle, in IE and Chrome. But as soon as I put it in my own work, it fails. I have even tried to remove every other CSS in my file, so it only have what you see in the JSFiddle, and removing everything in the body, except what you see in the JSFiddle as well.

The only thing left on the page, in the top, is:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test site</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

</head>
```

Don't know if I have explained it well enough. But does anyone have any idea of what's going on ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've added some pictures to show what I mean. 1st one is IE, 2nd is Chrome.

[image: Internet Explorer]
[image: Chrome]

Comment: You must have a conflicting rule in your style.css file

Comment: But shouldn't that be removed when I remove everything except what you see in the JSFiddle ?

Comment: Possibly; if the rule is in the style.css file, which you are still importing into your page, then you can have a conflict. We can only see what you have in the Fiddle, not your entire style file. I would recommend creating a **new** css file with **only** the rules you have in the fiddle and **nothing else**. See if it looks like the fiddle.

Comment: This is very weird, I've tested your code on my computer and no bugs..

Comment: Okay. Apparently, it had something to do with me storing all my websites/files on Skydrive. Even though they are set to Available offline, it made the difference. When I put the exact same files, with the exact same CSS and HTML on my desktop for example, it worked as intended. No idea why it is like that. But that's just something I have to think of in the future.
Thanks for all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that i see is transition is in wrong class you need to write it like this

```
ul.nav li a {
    font-family:'Gill Sans MT','Gill Sans', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:16px 10px 17px 10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border-top:3px rgba(255,255,255,0) solid;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#333333;
    webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
    border-top:3px #61a607 solid;
    background:rgba(97,166,7,0.05);

}
```

I don't see any color problem on my machine try with code it should work properly.